# PHP - DOMDocument load XML with encoded name

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript-2

Lets say that in my flash project I have script that create for me xml files dynamically (by PHP). XML file name is based on specific variable and escaped using `escape(variable)` in case that variable may (and mostly do) contains unsupported filename chars...

I need to know precise name of xml file later in my flash project, because I'm loading these XML files only if **`unescape(XMLfile) == variable`** . There's a lot of variables, so I can't just use `String.replace()` function to wipe out unsuported fileneme chars...

There's part of PHP file I'm using:

```
$XMLDom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xmlId = trim($_POST['xmlId']);
if(file_exists($xmlId)){
    $XMLDom ->load($xmlId);
}else{
    $newXMLHandler = fopen($xmlId, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fclose($newXMLHandler);

    $XMLDom ->load($xmlId);

    .... rest of the code ....

    $XMLDom ->save($xmlId);
}
```

The result of the code above is that in directory are 2 newly created XML files

One XML empty created by `fopen($xmlId, 'w')`, named: "**fi%20le%2C%2E%40.xml**"
and second one named: "**fi le,.@.xml**" where all my new XML data is stored...

Is there any way to load escaped named XML file by PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Arthur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel quite confident I understand your problem, but if your question was to find the analogue function to escape() in PHP, then [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) looks like the best match, but you need to research what exactly is being escaped. Note, for example, that there are several different ways to percent-encode strings, especially the multibyte strings. Flash may use `escapeMultibyte()` or it can also use `encodeURIComponent()` both encode different subsets of characters, and differently - so beware!

Now, regarding file names, if your HTTP server is running on Unix system, than "fi le,.@.xml" is a valid file name, nothing to worry about - inconvenient some times, but it is a legitimate name.

```
touch 'fi le,.@.xml'
```

would create a file, no problems there. Basically, the restricted characters are the slashes and the null character ("\x00"), but it is common to restrict also the characters that may be interpreted as shell commands - this is really up to you.

Comment: The problem is that XML won't be loaded from escaped (or urlencoded) named file. The DomDocument always unescaping the name which I request for and trying to load '**fi le,.@.xml**' instead of '**fi%20le%2C%2E%40.xml**' . These names are for example only, what about file called: '**/z\\*'c."l.xml**' ? There's no way even to save it. What I need is a string replacement for my variable which is fully allowed as file name, can be loaded as xml and decoded to original variable.

Comment: Yes, It works good with fopen(). Thanks for suggestion. I can't use any incrementing counter bacause all xml's are created based on user input ;)